# Keystore cannot load the key with ID: _androidx_security_master_key_

Tags: android, keystore

I am trying to use masterKey to encrypt shared prefs. However, sometimes my users are crashing due to invalidKeyException from keystore. I cannot reproduce this locally =\

```
 java.security.KeyStoreException: the master key android-keystore://_androidx_security_master_key_ exists but is unusable


 Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: Keystore cannot load the key with ID: _androidx_security_master_key_
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
    val masterKey = MasterKey.Builder(context)
        .setKeyGenParameterSpec(
            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS,
                PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or PURPOSE_DECRYPT
            )
                .setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
                .setKeySize(MasterKey.DEFAULT_AES_GCM_MASTER_KEY_SIZE)
                .build()
        )
        .build()
    securePrefs = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
        context,
        PREFERENCES,
        masterKey,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
        EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
    )
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Any clue why this occurs?

Comment: I was able to repro once when I wiped the simulator data and re-ran app. However, not able to repro 100%. No solution currently.

Comment: Wipe the emulator? but then why should it occur? Do you keep seeing this issue for users? Maybe it's on custom ROMs?

Comment: Yeah, we think it has to due with a cached user prefs / master key or something... We don't have ROMs logged. Maybe we'll look into that.

Comment: But if you wipe the emulator, the app and its data are gone, so how did you reproduce it? And how did you handle it for users? What did you do in code?

Comment: From android studio, I wiped the simulator using AVD, then re-ran the app. We are currently not handling it for users, we are getting crashes for them.

Comment: But if you re-run the app, it's clean of data, so it shouldn't occur. Do you have perhaps a POC you can share? If you indeed can reproduce it, you could add to an existing bug report, here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176215143 (or create a new one).

Comment: See https://github.com/google/tink/issues/535#issuecomment-912170221 for potential workarounds, I can confirm that this is still happening with the stable version as well

Answer (score 10):

The issue has been in detail reported to the Google bug tracker as well. Might be better to follow the discussions there.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176215143

Answer (score 1):

You can see Android issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/176215143?pli=1

I can suggest simple workaround with removing the data of preferences and key from a system KeyStore. With this fix after the reinstall your App can't restore the data. But at least your App could start from fresh page without crash. You could create some custom builder and use it to create the Encrypted Preferences:

```
class EncryptedPreferenceBuilder(val context: Context) {


companion object {
    private const val TAG = "EncryptedPreferenceBuilder"
    private const val KEYSTORE_PROVIDER = "AndroidKeyStore"
}

private val masterKeyAlias = MasterKey.Builder(context, MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS).setKeyScheme(MasterKey.KeyScheme.AES256_GCM).build()

fun build(prefName: String): SharedPreferences {
    return try {
        createSharedPreferences(prefName)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred while create shared preference")
        deleteSharedPreferences(prefName)
        deleteMasterKey()
        createSharedPreferences(prefName)
    }
}

private fun createSharedPreferences(prefName: String) = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
    context,
    prefName,
    masterKeyAlias,
    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
)

private fun clearSharedPreference(prefName: String) {
    context.getSharedPreferences(prefName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().clear().apply()
}

private fun deleteSharedPreferences(prefName: String) {
    try {
        clearSharedPreference(prefName)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            context.deleteSharedPreferences(prefName)
        } else {
            FileUtils.delete("${context.filesDir.parent}/shared_prefs/$prefName.xml")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error delete preferences")
    }
}

private fun deleteMasterKey() {
    try {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_PROVIDER)
        keyStore.load(null)
        keyStore.deleteEntry(MasterKey.DEFAULT_MASTER_KEY_ALIAS)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error delete MasterKey")
    }
}
}
```

Usage:

```
val prefs = EncryptedSharedPreferenceBuilder(context).build("APP_PREFS_NAME")
```